# mc: customizig colors with skins

Tags: colors, mc

I am editing the default skin for `midnight commander` and I would like to add some more rules for file highlighting. In the `filehighlight` section, there are several categories, for example `archive=red;` will display all `gz` files red.

```
[filehighlight]
    directory=white;
    executable=brightgreen;
    symlink=lightgray;
    hardlink=
    stalelink=brightred;
    device=brightmagenta;
    special=black;
    core=red;
    temp=gray;
    archive=red;
    doc=brown;
    source=cyan;
    media=green;
    graph=brightcyan;
    database=brightred;
```

I would like to add new rules, for example all `*.deb` files should have blue color. Is it possible to create new categories ? Where are these categories defined, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~/.config/mc/filehighlight.ini
/etc/mc/filehighlight.ini
```

See the `mc(1)` man page, section `Filenames Highlight`